# How to fix "Callback Error" in Plotly Dash when filtering on dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

Edit: I have updated the question and added additional info below.

I am working from the following code example: [Plotly Dash How-To](https://pbpython.com/plotly-dash-intro.html)

However, I am running into occasional errors when I attempt to filter base on my dropdown.

I am assuming that the error has to do with bad or invalid data in certain key pairs. Any advice on how to expose the content of the problem key pairs, what might be causing the issue, or any potential solutions are more than welcome. Thanks!

My current code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

s3path = 'https"//s3path.goes.here/file.csv'
  
df = pd.read_csv(s3path,index_col="Parent.CreatedOnUtc")
workflow_options = df['Parent.DisplayName'].unique()
df['workflow'] = df['Parent.DisplayName'] 
df['TOP'] = df['Parent.Status']
df['people'] = df['Parent.CreatedBy']
df['simpledate'] = df.index

df['simpledate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['simpledate'], 
                                        format='%Y-%m-%d', 
                                        errors='coerce')

df['simpledate'] = df['simpledate'].dt.date

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

print("Data Loaded")



app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Dashboard Title'),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="Workflow",
                options=[{
                    'label': i,
                    'value': i
                } for i in workflow_options],
                value='All Workflows'),
        ],
        style={'width': '25%',
               'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='funnel-graph'),
])



@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Workflow', 'value')])
def update_graph(Workflow):
    if Workflow == "All Workflows":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = df[df['Parent.DisplayName'] == Workflow]


    pv = pd.pivot_table(
        df_plot,
        index=['simpledate'], 
        columns=['TOP'], values=['Parent.Status'],
        aggfunc='count', 
        fill_value=0)

    print(pv)

    trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Parent.Status', 'Completed')], name='Completed')
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Parent.Status', 'Failed')], name='Failed')
    trace3 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Parent.Status', 'Cancelled')], name='Cancelled')
    trace4 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Parent.Status', 'Rejected')], name='Rejected')

    return {
        'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='Workflow Status by Date {}'.format(Workflow),
            barmode='stack')
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The errors that appear when I select some of my dropdown options are:

```
 Errors (1)
⛑️
Callback error updating funnel-graph.figure
9:04:09 AM
Callback error updating funnel-graph.figure


KeyError: ('Parent.Status', 'Failed')

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
 
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc
 
File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 708, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc
 
KeyError: ('Parent.Status', 'Failed')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
    
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    
KeyError: 'Failed'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc
    
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Failed'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 708, in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc
    
KeyError: ('Parent.Status', 'Failed')
```

Edit: ADDITIONAL INFO BELOW

After reviewing the comments, I pulled the pivot tables that are being created during the page load and discovered that when there are no occurrences of a particular Status type that instead of generating a zero-filled column, it does not create the column.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to populate the pivot table correctly to handle this circumstance?

Working Dataset:
[image: Working Dataset]

Broken Dataset (Missing columns that are being traced... i.e. 'Rejected'):
[image: Broken Dataset]

Comment: Do you have access to the data you're plotting? It looks like some of it may not include anything for the `Failed` values. If the data does not in fact have anything there, you could either fill with some default values, or check before you try to access it and output some default if it isn't found.

Comment: @coralvanda I have updated the question and included the datasets.